# Customization of a Stepper component (Nebular / Angular)

Tags: angular, nebular, stepper

I'd like to know if there's anyway I'm able to customize the scss/html template of a Nebular [Stepper component](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/stepper/overview#nbsteppercomponent). I found out that you can customize some of the scss using Nebular [Custom theming](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/design-system/create-custom-theme#create-custom-theme) but I need to change things that don't have theme variables, like the **Stepper Header** (Completed step icon, number appearance.. etc) and **Stepper connector** (Appearance, size.. etc)..

I'm somewhat new to angular/nebular components, so I don't know how to customize the scss/html template of pre-made components, can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach is to create your own theming in nebular instead of changing individual elements according to your need, but there is a way to achieve what you're trying as well.

To do that you'll need to find the classes related to the stepper, and then apply your styling in your global styling files

**NOT in the component styling. That won't work as nebular has global styling set up and it will override your styling, even if you use !important**

You can use the following classes for updating the stepper:

1. `.nb-theme-corporate nb-stepper .header .step.selected .label-index`

   This is for updating border/background colors for selected step
2. `.nb-theme-corporate nb-stepper .header .step.selected`

   This is for changing font styling for selected step

For all other steps, you just need to remove `.step.selected` and it will be applied

Comment: Hello, @Adnan thanks for the response I'll give it a go.. but, by global styling files you mean "styles.scss" &/or "themes.scss"?, if this is of any help, I'm using the ngx-admin ->  (https://akveo.github.io/ngx-admin/) template.

Comment: @AldimarJ yes, that's what I mean. Any styling file that's defined in angular.json

Comment: Thanks for the help, got it working using your tips!

Comment: You're most welcome :)